# typeof mongoose model instance

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I want to create a function that takes a mongoose model instance as its only parameter. For that I need to specify the Type; something like this

```js
function takeModelInstance(instance: TypeIDontKnowHowToSpecifiy) {
  // body doesn't matter
}
```

This is my Schema and Model creation code:

```js
interface Blog {
  title: string,
}

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Blog>({
  title: String,
});

const BlogModel = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

My approach:

```js
// type is inferred but doesn't help as output is very impractical:
//   mongoose.Model<Blog, {}, {}, {}, mongoose.Document<unknown, {}, Blog> & Omit<Blog & { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId; }, never>, any>
const demo1 = new BlogModel();

// does not produce an error straight away, but autocompletion such as `demo.title` doesn't work so something is wrong
const demo2: typeof BlogModel = new BlogModel();
```

**Edit:** I solved it with

```js
const demo3: InstanceType<typeof BlogModel> = new BlogModel();
```

Any easier solution will be appreciated and accepted! Thanks

Comment: Use a class? https://tsplay.dev/WKp5Dw I don't know if this breaks mongoose somehow, though. Make sure to test first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *mongoose v6.11.1* and *v7.1.0*, you can use `HydratedDocument<Blog>` type to

> represents a hydrated Mongoose document, with methods, virtuals, and other Mongoose-specific features.

See [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html)

I use [`expect-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect-type) to check if the `HydratedDocument<Blog>` type matches the `InstanceType<typeof BlogModel>` type.

```
import mongoose, { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { expectTypeOf } from 'expect-type';

interface Blog {
  title: string,
}

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Blog>({
  title: String,
});

const BlogModel = mongoose.model<Blog>('Blog', blogSchema);

function takeModelInstance(instance: HydratedDocument<Blog>) {

}

const demo3: InstanceType<typeof BlogModel> = new BlogModel();

expectTypeOf(demo3).toMatchTypeOf<HydratedDocument<Blog>>() // type check pass

// The expanded TS type of HydratedDocument<Blog> is:
// mongoose.Document<unknown, any, Blog> & Omit<Blog & {
//     _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
// }, never>
```

Comment: I cannot (and won't) test it, because I removed mongoose from all my apps and will certainly never touch it again. But what you wrote (HydratedDocument) makes sense, so I will blindly accept it.

Comment: @Pagenotfound What alternative ODM you are going to use?

Comment: none + pure typescript + zod + pure mongo schema. As a former PHP (lol) "developer" I was under the impression I need an ORM, Document Models etc. but this is actually totally against the spirit of a document storage and even the Mongodb dev team is more or less against it. (there is an official blog post somewhere) And it works surprisingly well without mongoose. I am not saying mongoose is bad, but the docs always have been a pain for me some portions of mongoose are completely untyped (callbacks) and thus pretty useless for full TS projects.